# Creating or updating a has_one ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been trying to get my head around `ActiveRecord` associations but I have hit a bit of a brick wall, and no matter how much I review the `ActiveRecord` documentation, I can't work out how to solve my problem.

I have two classes:

```
Property -> has_one :contract  
Contract -> belongs_to :property
```

In my contract class, I have a method to create_or_update_from_xml

First I check to make sure the property in question exists.

```
property_unique_id = xml_node.css('property_id').text
      property = Property.find_by_unique_id(property_unique_id)
      next unless property
```

And this is where I get stuck, I have a hash of attributes for the contract, and what I want to do is something like:

```
if property.contract.nil?
  # create a new one and populate it with attributes
else
  # use the existing one and update it with attributes
```

I know how I would go about it if it was raw SQL, but I can't get my head around hte ActiveRecord approach.

Any hints past this road block would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44):

```
if property.contract.nil?
  property.create_contract(some_attributes)
else
  property.contract.update_attributes(some_attributes)
end
```

Should do the trick. When you have a `has_one` or `belongs_to` association then you get `build_foo` and `create_foo` methods (which are like Foo.new and Foo.create). If the association already exists then `property.contract` is basically just a normal active record object.

Comment: maybe use blank?

Answer (score 38):

Just another way of doing it using ruby `OR-Equal` trick

```
property.contract ||= property.build_contract
property.contract.update_attributes(some_attributes)
```

Update:

@KayWu is right, the above ||= trick will create the contract object in the first line, rather than just building it. An alternative would be

```
property.build_contract unless property.contract
property.contract.update_attributes(some_attributes)
```

Comment: When you assign an object to a has_one association, that object is automatically saved, which may break validations.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference
use property.build_contract unless property.contract instead.

Comment: update_attributes is deprecated from Rails 6.1. You might want to update your answer to use update instead

Answer (score 15):

```
Property.all.each do |f|
  c = Contract.find_or_initialize_by(property_id: f.id)
  c.update(some_attributes)
end
```

I don't know whether this is the best solution, but for me it more succinctly

Answer (score 2):

From Rails 6.1 an onwards:

```
property.build_contract unless property.contract
property.contract.update(some_attributes)
```